# BlenderGIS: import Georeference Raster onto Delaunay Mesh

Tags: objects, import

I have two files.  One is an elevation in points (SHP file), the other is a photo GeoTIFF.  Both the elevation SHP and the photo TIF have the same exact projection and the same exact geographic coordinates in EPSG:3857 WGS84.  I import the shape file and then turn it into a Delaunay Mesh.  Looks great.  I then try to import the Geotiff as a Georeference Raster onto it and I get "cannot reproj raster."  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From studying the code I found [here](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/blob/master/io_georaster/op_import_georaster.py), I found out that the CRS in Blender for the elevation didn't match the CRS I was importing...probably my mistake when I imported it.  I fixed that...the image then imported, but it imported on the bottom of the elevation instead of on top.  I'm trying to import it on the mesh so there must be something in the code that's selecting that face...or I'm doing something else wrong.